# webservices - public certificate update

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee

I'm not very familiar with web services security concepts but **as a provider of web services, we have to update the public cert in our `.jks`  file**.

Should we share anything to the consumers of this service to update at their end?

Consumers sign their messages and sends the request. The service end-point is on HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

> Consumers sign their messages and send the request

Signing messages involves the private key of the one who does the signing, in your case the client. [See here for some intro details](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jws5/) of how this stuff works. Changing the web service certificate (the public key) might not cause problems (certificates are updated on a constant basis on the internet for HTTPS sites and no browser starts spewing errors, for example) but at the same time your clients might fail if you are using message level security.

If you encrypt at the message level (the data that gets exchanged) instead of encryption at the transport level (how the data is sent - over HTTPS instead of HTTP) then you need to notify your clients.

You don't mention how the exchange is secured so maybe find out about that first. If the endpoint is on HTTP as you mentioned then it's message level security which means you service might sign or encrypt the message for itself so changing the keys will alter the signature and your clients will not trust the response anymore.

If you are still in doubt about what you need to do then find someone who does know what to do, then notify your clients before doing the change so they have time to make changes themselves if needed. They can decide for themselves if this has or hasn't an impact on them. Whatever you do though, don't give them your new private key.